# Monkey patching a python class method from a library

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I'm importing a library someone else made and I'm wanting to change the way a particular class method works from that library so I've copied the class method to my own file and wanting to replace it at runtime. This seems to work just fine for functions but seems to fall apart for class methods.

`a.library.package.library_file.py`

```py
class LibraryClass(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_cost(cls, time):
        return int(time * cls.hourly)
```

I'm wanting to replace it with this

```py
class LibraryClass(ParentClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_cost(cls, time):
        return 1234
```

I've tried to just do a normal replace which works just fine for regular functions

```py
import a.library.package.library_file

...

a.library.package.library_file.LibraryClass.get_cost = get_cost
```

But it doesn't seem to work right at all, the method is called with the wrong arguments at the wrong time and results in a crash. After some research on Google, StackOverflow, and Python I began trying to use the mock classes.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch.object('a.library.package.library_file.LibraryClass', 'get_cost')
def get_cost(cls, time):
    return 1234
```

The good news is it doesn't crash, bad news is it doesn't do anything, the old code is still there and it's like my code doesn't exist.

I've tried all kinds of other ways to do this such as

```py
import a.library.package.library_file

@patch.object(a.library.package.library_file.LibraryClass, 'get_cost')
...
```

or

```py
from a.library.package.library_file import LibraryClass

@patch.object(LibraryClass, 'get_cost')
...
```

but every time the method is never touched. It's like my code doesn't exist and the old code is used.

Answer (score 11):

It turns out the solution was simple as I thought it might be. It took more than a day of digging and there's just no help anywhere online but I found an obscure random post from china on page 2 of Google which finally answered my question. [Link Here](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=https://blog.csdn.net/lslxdx/article/details/78182851&prev=search&pto=aue)

This is the resulting code that works

```py
from types import MethodType
from a.library.package.library_file.py import LibraryClass

def get_cost(cls, time):
    return 1234


LibraryClass.get_cost = MethodType(get_cost, LibraryClass)
```

It's the same as replacing a function only you need to wrap it in "MethodType" because the code your swapping out has "classmethod" ties to the class and so the new code needs to be tied the same in order to work.

Comment: I think it's even a little simpler, just `LibraryClass.get_cost = classmethod(get_cost)`.

Comment: The suggestion from @rascalking is not just simpler - it works in situations where the `MethodType` approach does not - e.g. for subclasses, the `cls` argument is correctly set to the subclass when using `classmethod` but is always set to the base class if you use `MethodType`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just import the original class and create your own class that inherits from the original class ? Then you redefine the method that you want to override and just use your custom class instead of the original class:

```
from a_library import LibraryClass

class YourClass(LibraryClass):
    @classmethod
    def get_cost(cls, time):
        # redefine the method here
        return 1234

cost = YourClass.get_cost(time)
```

Then just use `YourClass` instead of the library class. It will behave exactly like the library class, but with your method instead of the original method.

Comment: No because many other code uses the class from the library. I'm trying to change some code for an existing system so I need all instances of that class and other code that uses it to begin using my code instead. This is the reason why I'm replacing the code and not just overriding it.

Comment: Ok, did you install the library you're modifying with pip ?

Comment: I didn't, I'm making a python plugin for an existing system.

Comment: To make the approach in this answer work, you could have followed up by monkey-patching the original `LibraryClass` with `YourClass.get_cost`.